# run a sql file inside a sql file postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to load/run a sql file from inside another sql file.

Because my goal is to have one sql file with all the table creations and then after each create statment I let run the <table-name>-data.sql to insert the data for the table.

I just dont know what the rigth sql command is for that because copy is only for csv files.
And load is for shared libarys.

> LOAD — load a shared library file

File with the data from a table:

`<table-name>-data.sql`:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.table VALUES ('2022-11-16');
INSERT INTO public.table VALUES ('2022-11-17');
INSERT INTO public.table VALUES ('2022-11-18');
INSERT INTO public.table VALUES ('2022-11-19');
```

File where I create the table and then load <table-name>-data.sql:

`create.sql`:

```sql
... sql for creating the table ...

run "c:/path/<table-name>-data.sql"
```

And in the end I can just run the create.sql file.

Comment: I can't speak for PosgreSQL, but there's normally no SQL statement to load scripts, that tends to be an internal command of whatever tool you use to process the files. In e.g. [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) you have `\i` / `\include`.

Comment: Thank you so much I knew that I could use this command, because that's how I run the create.sql, but I thought this would work only when I call it in psql and not in the sql file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by @Álvaro González,

Just use: `\i path/file.sql`

You can use it inside SQL too when trying it to run with psql.